# Multiply imputing data, but using just one of the imputed data sets

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

All,

I have a question about what's practical when it comes to presenting results of multiply imputed data. I'm well-versed on the difference among MCAR/MAR/MNAR and approaches to imputing the data itself. I even know about Rubin's rules and how to synthesize results from multiply imputed data sets.

To give some background on my project. I'm estimating a series of multilevel models with the `lme4` package on some survey data. To give some more background about the data project. I have about 250,000 total respondents in 85 countries. Some countries are surveyed multiple times, leading to about 145 country-years. I have individual-level (i.e. respondent-level) predictors and country-level (i.e. macro-level) predictors. The macro-level predictors are of interest to me.

Given the missingness on some of the individual-level predictors, I'd have about half those observations. Listwise deleting them would severely bias the results on the macro-level predictors toward the null hypothesis. If I were to just estimate the macro-level predictors on the outcome variable (which is individual-level), the results I get conform well to the results of the five multiply imputed data sets I generated using the `Amelia` program in `R`.

However, I'm encountering several problems associated with the multiple imputation.

- The model converges, but takes forever to converge.
- Simulating quantities of interest with the `Zelig` package (and `ZeligMultilevel`) chokes because it (presently) doesn't do well in simulating quantities of interest with multiply imputed data. The output just gets too big and `R` crashes.

I do have these features of the imputed data.

- All five imputed data sets are roughly similar to each other. No one imputation gives drastically different results.
- The overall results (aggregated using Rubin's rules) conform well to a bare-bones mixed effects model that has just the macro-level predictors (and, thus, no concern of bias due to missing data).

My question is simple: can I just pick one of the multiply imputed data sets and run my analyses on that? It would be simpler, more time-efficient, and would not deviate at all from the results of the five data sets aggregated using Rubin's rules. I could also more easily provide quantities of interest using the `Zelig` package, which is what I really want to do.

I think this would be practical, even if it's not "by the books". I'm curious if there are important arguments to be made against this approach I'm suggesting.

Comment: Well, if you were to treat your single dataset as though it had been observed, then you wouldn't be accounting for the uncertainty in the imputed data, which you do when you use multiple imputed datasets then pool results using Rubin's rules.

Comment: I actually am well aware of this. What I'm saying is that no one imputation is considerably different at all from the results of all five aggregated using Rubin's rules.